# Setting child's height when parent's height is set via padding-top

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has a percentage with and to maintain a certain aspect ratio i use the padding-top on :after method. As i can see, the browser sets the height properly. Then the container has a child elemtn(s) with percentage height and width. But it doesn't work. what am i missing?

```
.parent {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;    
    outline: 1px solid black;    
}
.parent:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 50%;
}

.child {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    outline: 1px dashed red;   
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px27gx4h/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `position`,
`padding` will only add space of aspect ratio - so you need to use `position:a
bsolute` to content to ignore this space and `position:relative` to parent to be able to position it as you intend

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*margin: 5px;*/
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dotted green;
}

.parent {
    position:relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;    
    outline: 1px solid black;    
}
.parent:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 50%; /*15*/
  }

.child {
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    outline: 1px dashed red;   
}
.content {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="child">Child</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to work. But if those elements needed to be floated, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use percentage for height unless the parent elements height is explicitly declared.  Otherwise the height will have no effect and is as if it were not there at all.  According to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **<percentage>**
>   Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block. Note: For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a block-level element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the padding box of that element. This is a change from CSS1, where the percentage was always calculated with respect to the content box of the parent element.

Comment: he can if he use `position:relative` to parent

Comment: True enough, still it is worth knowing that the reason it's not working is because of the way the spec is designed.  Regardless, your solution to the issue does the trick just fine.